# Open and Edit Excel file using Excel Access Web Part and Generate Charts in SP 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, chart, excel-access-web-part

I want to open and edit the Excel file in SharePoint 2010 and I need to insert/generate the charts based on the information within the excel file.

For this purpose, I tried Excel Web Access web part to display excel sheet in SharePoint but unable to edit it.

How to edit,save and generate charts within SharePoint Page itself using this web part?